# Bootstrap x-editable. Change data type programmatically (Remove select2 data-type)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

I'm, using bootstrap x-editable https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html

This is my html code:

```
<a href="#" data-name="category" class="addon" data-value="{{$cat->id}}"
   data-pk="{{$cat->id}}" data-type="select2" data-title="Favor llenar los campos"></a>
```

javascript code:

```
$('.addon').editable({
    placement: 'bottom',
    mode: 'inline',
    showbuttons: false,
    source: categories,
    select2: {
        width: 200
    },
    display: function (value) {
        var elem = $.grep(categories, function (o) {
            return o.id == value;
        });

        $(this).attr('data-value', value);
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.btnEdit').attr('href', '/wizard_product/' + product_id + '/category/' + value + '/edit');

        return $(this).text(elem[0].text);
    }
});
```

But. I want to change programmatically to normal x-editable element without the select2 options.

I have tried with jquery to change the data-type attribute of the a element to text, but it does not work.

```
$('a.addon').attr('data-type', 'text');
```

Also tried:

```
$('a.addon').select2('destroy');
```

Also tried:

```
$('a.addon').editable({type: 'text'});
```

But neither options work. select2 is still active.
How can I remove select2 options of x-editable?
 Can you help me please

Comment: Can you add your `categories` data and also it would be better if you can provide a working example like a fiddle or snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to combine the things that you've tried - destroy the default X-editable instance, change the `data-type` value, and reinstate X-editable on that element.

The most simple implementation/example would be:

```
$('.addon').editable('destroy').data('type', 'text').editable({type: 'text'});
```

In practice, you'll have to put your other settings back when you re-apply X-editable as text:

```
$('.addon').editable('destroy');
$('.addon').data('type', 'text');
$('.addon').editable({
                placement: 'bottom',
                mode: 'inline',
                showbuttons: false,
                source: categories,
                type: 'text',
                display: function (value) {
                    var elem = $.grep(categories, function (o) {
                        return o.id == value;
                    });
                    $(this).attr('data-value', value);

                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.btnEdit').attr('href', '/wizard_product/' + product_id + '/category/' + value + '/edit');
                    return $(this).text(elem[0].text);
                }
            });
```

Edit:

I've put together a demo that mirrors your setup as best I could tell and it seems to work:

```js
var categories = [{
  id: 'html',
  value: 'html',
  text: 'html'
}, {
  id: 'javascript',
  value: 'javascript',
  text: 'javascript'
}];

setupSelect2();

$('#useSelect2').click(function() {
  $('.addon')
    .data('type', 'select2')
    .editable('destroy');

  setupSelect2();
});

$('#useText').click(function() {
  $('.addon')
    .data('type', 'text')
    .editable('destroy');

  setupText();
});

function setupSelect2() {
  $('.addon').editable({
    mode: 'inline',
    placement: 'bottom',
    showbuttons: false,
    source: categories,
    select2: {
      width: 200
    },
    display: function(value) {
      var elem = $.grep(categories, function(o) {
        return o.id == value;
      });

      $(this).attr('data-value', value);

      if (elem[0])
        return $(this).text(elem[0].text);
    }
  });
}

function setupText() {
  $('.addon').editable({
    mode: 'inline',
    placement: 'bottom',
    type: 'text',
    showbuttons: false,
    source: categories,
    display: function(value) {
      var elem = $.grep(categories, function(o) {
        return o.id == value;
      });

      $(this).attr('data-value', value);

      if (elem[0])
        return $(this).text(elem[0].text);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/select2/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/bootstrap300/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/bootstrap300/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<link href="https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/select2/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h3>Select 2</h3>
<a href="#" class="addon" data-type="select2" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter tags"></a>
<br>
<br>
<button id="useSelect2" class="btn btn-default">Use Select2</button>
<button id="useText" class="btn btn-default">Use Text</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have already done that. But It does not work either

Comment: Maybe something else is going on?  If you go to their [demo page](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html), open a dev console (F12) and execute `$('#tags').editable('destroy').data('type', 'text').editable({type: 'text'});`, it should demonstrate the behavior I think you're looking for on the select2 demo (3rd from the bottom).